# What is the Java naming convention for list of objects which have plural forms ending with "ies" or non-standard "s" plural forms?

Tags: java, javabeans

I am unable to find any naming conventions for Java that covers the usage of words that does not follow the standard "s" plural form.

```
//Given a list of biologies, what should the getter method be?

private List<Biology> biologies;

public Biology getBiology();
public List<Biology> getBiologies();
```

What is the convention when the plural form is much different?

```
//Given a list of octopi, what should the getter method be?

private List<Octopus> octopi;

public Octopus getOctopus();
public List<Octopus> getOctopi();
```

Comment: The plural of octopus is octopuses. The "octopi" comes from the false belief that octopus is of Latin extraction, when it is from the Greek instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is on the edge of opinion, but I'm calling "best practice" and saying:

Use plurals and spell them correctly.

Just as you should spell *all* variables/fields correctly (abbrevations of long terms being acceptable if clear, eg `min`, `max` etc).

---

Not authorative, but Intellij auto-generates correctly spelled plurals, eg:

```
List<Company> x; // "companies" will be auto-suggested if you rename "x"
```

Comment: I would certainly reject at code review any code with a spelling error.